# Clang tidy replace reinterpret_cast with static_cast

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

Is there any rule which makes clang tidy to warn about useless reinterpret_cast where static_cast can be used ?
E.g.

```
void f(void* p)
{
    int* x = reinterpret_cast<int*>(p);
    // static_cast is enough here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such check in clang-tidy.

If you need this check, you'll have to write it yourself. There is a similar one that can be used as a starting point - [google-readability-casting](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/google-readability-casting.html) checks for C-style casts and can automatically fix them in cases static_cast is sufficient.

Comment: What do you mean write by myself ? Change clang-tidy code ?

Comment: Yes, clang-tidy is open source, you are free to write your own checks. There is even documentation available for writing checks.